# Symfony2 trying to write to the previous server it was running on?

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I've been developing a Symfony2 app locally and am now at the stage where I would like to deploy it in it's production environment on a server.

I've uploaded all my files and tried to run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Which gives the following error:

[image]

As you can see, it's trying to write to my C:/ drive for some reason. Doing a regular cache:clear works fine, but I can't swap it to the production environment.

At this point, trying to use the app.php version simply loads a blank page. I can't figure out why my app would be trying to write to a directory on a previous server.

Help?

Comment: remove cache folder manually and create a new one with the right permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try empty the cache folder
`rm -rf app/cache/*`
After this the cache:clear --env=prod command work properly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I moved my application from domain.com/dev/ to domain.com/ but I get a http 500 error when trying to load either the app.php or app_dev.php versions... any ideas?

Comment: I started another question with the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828294/symfony2-application-returning-500-from-both-app-php-and-app-dev-php but have managed to get things working. :-)